# Place finish button at the end

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I want to implement Primefaces wizard with finish button at the bottom. Example code:

```
<h:form>

                    <p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true"/>

                    <p:wizard flowListener="#{newSensor.onFlowProcess}">
                        <p:tab id="personal" title="General">
                            <p:panel header="Sensor Details">
                                <p:messages />
                                <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                                    ......

                                    <h:outputText value="Enabled " />
                                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{newSensor.sensor.enabled}" />
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </p:panel>
                        </p:tab>

                        <p:tab id="confirm" title="Confirmation">
                            <p:panel header="Confirmation">
                                <h:panelGrid id="confirmation" columns="3" columnClasses="grid,grid,grid">
                                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                                        ......

                                        <h:outputText value="Age: " />
                                        <h:outputText value="#{newSensor.sensor.enabled}" styleClass="outputLabel"/>
                                    </h:panelGrid>
                                </h:panelGrid>

                                <p:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{newSensor.save}" update="growl" process="@this"/>
                            </p:panel>
                        </p:tab>
                    </p:wizard>

                </h:form>
```

Want to get this visual result:

[image]

How I can get this visual result?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to implement your own UI for the navigation and just control when the Submit button will be displayed.

First hide the navigation bar as such:

```
<p:wizard showNavBar="false" widgetVar="wiz">
...
</p:wizard>
```

Then just create some codes for the `NEXT,BACK,SUBMIT, ETC.`

```
<p:outputPanel id="updateAsNeeded">
<h:outputLink value="#" onclick="PF('wiz').next();">Next</h:outputLink>
<h:outputLink value="#" onclick="PF('wiz').back();">Back</h:outputLink>
<p:commandButton value="Submit" rendered="#{bean.isEndReached}">Submit</p:commandButton>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Then you define a FlowListener to determine :

```
<p:wizard flowListener="#{bean.handleFlow}">
...
</p:wizard>
```

For your bean:

```
public String handleFlow(FlowEvent event) {
String currentStepId = event.getCurrentStep();
String stepToGo = event.getNextStep();


//check if stepToGo is on the last page
//endReached = true;

RequestContext.update("updateAsNeeded");

return event.getNextStep();
}
```

Hope this helps or guides you forward.

Comment: Is there any solution without custom UI navigation?

Comment: well maybe you can just use the handleFlow part. But I don't think you can align the Submit button with the Back button with it.

Comment: For example can I somehow set the finish button at the end of the flow?

Comment: @Kukeltje I fully agree. About the question - can you propose some solution?

Comment: as I said, you can just use the handleFlow part and just conditionally render your SUBMIT button when you've reached the last page of the wizard. You can't just use CSS here since there's a bit of a logic when it will appear.